# Strip out rest of query string after first ampersand

Tags: php, regex, query-string

I am trying to remove the query string from a url, but I need to leave the first key/var intact. So I know what first occurrence of an ampersand is the point from which I want to discard the query string. What would the best way to do this? Below is my code, which currently just keeps appending to the query string.

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?>&sortkey=year&sortval=asc">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly, you want to strip out everything after 1st occurrence of ampersand. You can use something like this:

```
<?php
$uri = 'blah.blah.com?a=b&sortkey=year&sortval=asc';
$new_uri = preg_replace("/([^&]+)&(.*)/", "$1", $uri)
?>
```

The pattern:

```
([^&]+) : Match everything except '&'
&       : First '&'
(.*)    : Any thing after that
```

Is replaced by first group (`$1`), which is anything before first occurrence of `&`.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply match for everything that is not an ampersand until we hit the first ampersand. E.g.

```
$incomingURI = 'http://www.example.com/?id=12&left=right&up=down';
preg_match('/[^&]+/', $incomingURI, $match);
$outgoingURI = $match[0];
```

*The above code will output the following in variable $outgoingURI:*

```
http://www.example.com/?id=12
```

This will be much quicker than using a preg_replace.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. But you have an extra `+` in the regex.

Comment: @rvighne The additional `+` was not a typo. In PCRE used in PHP the additional `+` makes the expression possessive. If an ampersand is not found it will not backtrack to look again. Looking back on this code now the speed increase is practically non existent since we are only looking for 1 character and that is in a small string but the double plus syntax was fine.

Answer (score 1):

With the [strpos](http://php.net/strpos) function find the location of the ampersand. Then with the [substr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) function get the part of the URL until that point.

Answer (score 0):

strpos will work, but unless you are using RewriteRule, $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] or $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] should suffice (and presumably more efficient).

If the URL IS being rewritten, then $_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL'] is more appropriate.

EDIT: I missed the bit about keeping first part of query string :s